# I can read but not set cookies in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, variable-assignment

It's the weirdest thing. When I ran the Rails WEBrick debugger yesterday I could do things like

```
cookies[uid] = s.session_id
```

where 'uid' is a passed argument that has a user id in it, and then expect

```
cookies[uid]
```

to give me back, say:

```
29b93443d9ec18168a26e1ab12957b0dd0b799ff
```

Today, I always get back 'nil'. I can read existing values just fine. Any of the keys listed in

```
cookies.keys
```

work just fine.

Does anyone have a possible explanation for this behavior. It is very maddening, and a Google search hasn't yielded an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Original questioner, here. It turns out that I can set those cookies. The issue is that when you type

```
cookies[:key]
```

in the debugger, it seems to always give you the value of the cookie as it was read from the browser. I don't know where the value gets stored away in the meantime, but inspecting the cookies in the browser confirms that my changes are indeed present. Usefully, cookies[:key] returns the value of the assignment, so you could probably do something like

```
@future_value = cookies[:key] = {
                                 :value => 'new value',
                                 :expires => @really_soon
                                }
```

I don't know what made me think I could view them before!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you need to read cookies using a string, rather than a symbol since Rails converts the keys to strings when you set them.

```
cookies[:key] = "value"
cookies[:key]  # => nil
cookies['key'] # => "value"
```